# Convert Power to Product multiplication format

Tags: formatting

I need to convert input expressions with explicit powers e.g.:

- $x^2 + 2*y^6$

to this format:

- $xx + 2 y y y y y y$

or this:

- $x*x + 2*y*y*y*y*y*y$

and then preserve this new format for other conversions using *HoldForm[...]*.
Is any way how to do this as easily as possible?
I have idea to do some parsing in cycle in this way:

- $2*y^6$ >> $2*y^5*y$ >> $2*y^4*y*y$ >> ... >> $2*y*y*y*y*y*y$

But it seems to be too complicated.

Comment: What kind of "other conversions" do you need to do? Perhaps there might be a way of doing those without having to this present conversion...

Comment: I have to replace different occurences of same variable with some values i.e. y^6 is only 1 occurence of variable y and  I need get 6 occurences.
I have alredy written code for this purpose so I only need to convert input. Maybe easier way will be to do it in some other editor but I am interested if it is feasible in mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps

```
f = #/. Power[a_,b_]:>(Inactive[Times]@@ConstantArray[a,b])&

f[x^2+2 y^5]
(*  x*x+2 (y*y*y*y*y) *)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: @blenderman, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. And welcome to mma.se.